# C# CodeProvider Error: Constructor on type not found

Tags: c#

I get the error: Constructor on type 'SimpleScript.Generator' not found.

I tried passing the correct parameters but i still get this error, this is my source code, and the script is a very simple piece of code that generates the Array of Element head and body. And also it is compiled successfully but it throws the error at the execution line.

```
string source = @"

using System;
using MSiteDLL;
namespace SimpleScript
{
    public static class Generator
    {
        public static Document Generate(Data server)
        {
            "+script+ @"
                    Block[] blocks = {
                    new Block(""head"", head),
                    new Block(""body"", body),
                    };
            return new Document(blocks);
        } 
    }
}

";
            Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"CompilerVersion", "v4.0"}
                };
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

            CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
            {
                GenerateInMemory = true,
                GenerateExecutable = false,
                ReferencedAssemblies = {
        "System.dll",
        "System.Core.dll",
        "MSiteDLL.dll",
    }
            };

            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);

            if (results.Errors.Count != 0)
            {
                string output = "";
                foreach (CompilerError y in results.Errors)
                {
                    output += y.ErrorText + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                throw new Exception("Compile failed:" + output);
            }
            object o = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("SimpleScript.Generator");
            MethodInfo mi = o.GetType().GetMethod("Generate");
            Data[] parametersArray = new Data[] { server };
            Document x = (Document)mi.Invoke(o, parametersArray);
            return x;
```

Comment: You're trying to instanciate a `static` class, which you can't do.

Comment: I removed the static keywrod and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :D

Comment: See the answer I posted, since I believe removing the `static` keyword does work but isn't what you should be doing. If you have no reason to instanciate a Generator, you should simply call the method without specifying a target (i.e. using `null` as the first parameter of `invoke`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your class is static, you should invoke the method in a static way.
So first, remove this line:

```
object o = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("SimpleScript.Generator");
```

And use those to invoke:

```
MethodInfo mi = Type.GetType("SimpleScript.Generator").GetMethod("Generate");
Data[] parametersArray = new Data[] { server };
Document x = (Document)mi.Invoke(null, parametersArray);
```

Comment: Made a quick edit because I forgot to remove `o` from the `MethodInfo` line. Using `Type.GetType("SimpleScript.Generator")` should get you the type.